# Android Value of SharedPreferences is not updating while app is running

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have 2 activity say for e.g MainActivity and PlayActivity.
I am retrieving value of currentLevel from SharedPreferences in MainActivity using following code.

```
sharedPreferences= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
     // comment this to see if value is saved or not
    currentLevel=sharedPreferences.getInt("currentlevel",1);
```

and I am Updating value of currentLevel in PlayActivity using following code.

```
sharedPreferences= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putInt("currentlevel",currentLevel+1);
    editor.apply();
```

Now my problem is while running app i am not able to update its value. For e.g while i am in PlayActivity and i won a level and i updated value of Shared Preference but while running app if i go back to MainActivity and try to retrieve CurrentLevel value, i got previous value not updated one.
Please Help. One more thing if i push updated of my app in future will sharedPrefrence also get updated with default 1 value or it will retain its previous value.

Comment: Hello Krish, welcome to SO. Judging by your last question, I'm going to assume you're relatively new to Android. Have you taken a look at the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences) on Shared Preferences usage? Your `PreferenceManager` usage is frowning, as it's been deprecated. Try (this new one) instead: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings

Comment: hello Martin, Yes i am very much new to android and i am trying to learn android by my own. i tried everything (Just like hit and try) but value of sharedprefrence is not updating while jumping from one activity to other.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? I have started facing this problem out of the blue

Answer (score 0):

```
sharedPreferences= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putInt("currentlevel",currentLevel+1);
    editor.commit();
```

Comment: Please explain what you did, not just paste code (that is also not necessarily correct). There's a reason why Apply is preferred.

Comment: From the doc: Note that you must call Editor#commit to have any changes you perform in the Editor actually show up in the SharedPreferences.

Comment: I used getApplicationContext(), because I am not sure which context you using, service or activity,  that's why I used application context, you can pass activity context to your Preference and use that context

Comment: If you inside of  a service then you will need to do some work for passing the right context (app context), meaning that you need to write an application call which super will be Android Application class .

Comment: @MartinMarconcini i tried changing code  MainActivity. ' sharedPreferences=getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("com.mathriddle", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
currentLevel=sharedPreferences.getInt("currentlevel",1);   '         PlayActivity ' sharedPreferences= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putInt("currentlevel",currentLevel);
        editor.apply(); '    yet same problem. value is not updated instant i have to close and open app to see updated value.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't here for a while, if you still facing the problem, then you have to catch an event for your level up, inside that event you have to update your pref, please update your question with activity code related to level-up, make sure you are logging successfuly inside your level up condition.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a quick sample for you to inspect. It's a "Empty Activity" project (as per the latest Android Studio template) with all defaults (in Kotlin).

After the project was created, I added a second Empty Activity (via the same template), and then I modified their layouts to have an Edit Text and a button.

#### What do Activities do when they start?

1. Load any existing Shared Preference value.
2. Populate the EditText with the existing value (which defaults to 0)

#### What does button click do?

1. Save existing value into shared preferences.
2. Launches next (or previous) activity.

Activity 1 goes to Activity 2, and Activity 2 goes back to 1.

Notice how no matter what number and what activity you use, the other picks it right away.

Here's where I left the project for your inspection:

https://github.com/Gryzor/MySharedPreferences

If you don't want to bother with a git clone, here's what Activity 1 does:

```
        // Obtain our private Shared Preferences 
        // This comes from ContextWrapper.
        val sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("sample", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

        // restore existing value
        val current = sharedPreferences.getInt("A_NUMBER", 0)
        editText.setText("$current")

        button.setOnClickListener {
            val text = editText.text.toString()

            val value = try {
                text.toInt()
            } catch (e: NumberFormatException) {
                0
            }

            // Save the current value
            sharedPreferences.edit().putInt("A_NUMBER", value).apply()

            // ... and go to the next activity
            val intent = Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
            finish()
        }
```

The other activity is identical, sans the intent line:

`val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)`

#### Conclusion

What I wanted to point out with all this nonsense, is that you are mismanaging your instances and not correctly using *something*. It's hard to tell because we haven't seen your source code.

Good luck :-)